# return RSS attribute values via BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, attributes, rss, beautifulsoup

**RSS: (in a file called myfeed.rss)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:newznab="http://www.newznab.com/DTD/2010/feeds/attributes/">
    <channel>
    <title>MyFeed</title>
    <link>http://website</link>
    <description>RSS Feed</description>
    <language>en-us</language>

            <item>
                <title>title goes here</title> 
                <pubDate>Tue, 09 Jun 2015 15:15:23 -0600</pubDate>
                <category>x264</category>
                <link>https://link_goes_here</link>
                <description>various HTML goes here</description>
                <guid>https://another_link_goes_here</guid>
                <newznab:attr name="category" value="6000" />
                <newznab:attr name="category" value="6040" />

                <newznab:attr name="size" value="1923203792" />

                <newznab:attr name="grabs" value="3" />

                <newznab:attr name="comments" value="0" />
                <newznab:attr name="password" value="0" />
                <newznab:attr name="usenetdate" value="Tue 09 Jun 2015 15:15:23 -0600" />
            </item>

    </channel>
    </rss>
```

**Python script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

handler = open('myfeed.rss').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(handler, 'xml')

for item in soup.findAll('item'):
    print item
    print("-----------------------------------")
    print item.findAll('newznab:attr')
```

The result: item prints in total. My separator line prints. But none of the newznab attributes are printed.

The problem: how do I get access to each of the '**newznab**' attributes? At present, I have been unable to work out how to retrieve these as dictionaries. I'm fairly new to Python. :)

Thanks.

edit: thanks to the suggestion by Rick, I've now been able to access these attributes as per:

**updated Python script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

handler = open('myfeed.rss').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(handler, 'lxml')

for item in soup.findAll('item'):
    print item
    print("-----------------------------------")

    newznabs = item.findAll('newznab:attr')
    newz_dict = {}

    for attribute in newznabs:
        newz_dict[attribute['name'].split(".")[0]] = attribute['value'].split(".")[0]

    print("newz_dict: [{}]".format(newz_dict))
    print("size: [{}]".format(newz_dict['size']))

    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
```

and now I have the attributes in a dictionary. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telling BeautifulSoup to use the `lxml` parser seems to keep self closing tags.

Try using:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(handler, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Thanks Rick - that certainly made things easier. :)

Comment: No problem! It seems strange to me that the `xml` parser handles that case differently.